# IISCommitdelay and Powershell memory usage

Tags: powershell, iis

When using Start-IISCommitDelay and Stop-IISComitDelay inside a for-each loop, memory usage skyrockets on many iterations.

[Powershell uses 1.5 GB memory on 100 loops.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0xq3.png)

If I move them outside the loop, into -begin and -end, the memory usage seems "normal", whatever normal is.
Memory is not released, not even after trying to invoke garbage collection
`(\[System.GC\]::Collect())`.
Does anyone know why this happens - what IISCommitdelay actually does?

There seems to be no notable time difference
It is a little weird to me - if changes were committed after each website was created, that should free up memory instead of use more.
So - it's probably PowerShell holding on to information. But why

I'm not trying to solve any real or perceived problem here, it is not often that I need to create 1000 websites in one take.
But I am trying to understand what IISCommitDelay does and why i does it. And why this happens, so to be a better scriptwriter.
Information on the subject is sparse - only vague descriptions exists.

Tried the following. Did not expect excessive memory usage.

```PowerShell
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
#Requires -PSEdition Desktop
#Requires -Version 5.1
#Requires -Modules webadministration, iisadministration

Import-Module iisadministration 
Import-Module webadministration 
$NumberOfnewWebsites = 1..100
$BindingPort = 80   # Bindingport is the place to start - script will test ports until it finds an unused port and use that port for the website.    
$NumberOfnewWebsites | ForEach-Object -Begin { 
    $WebsiteNumber = 0
    $PortsInUse = (Get-NetTCPConnection | Where-Object localport -GE $BindingPort).LocalPort | Sort-Object
    $Bindingports = $NumberOfnewWebsites
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $NumberOfnewWebsites.Count; $i++) {
        $BindingPortInUse = $true
        while ($BindingPortInUse) {
            if ($BindingPort -in $PortsInUse) { $Bindingport = $BindingPort + 1
            } else {
                $BindingPortInUse = $false
                $Bindingports[$i] = $BindingPort
                $Bindingport = $BindingPort + 1
            }
        }
    }
    # Start-IISCommitDelay
    
} -Process {
    Start-IISCommitDelay
    
    $WebsiteNameTemplate = "TestWebsite" # Actual WebsiteName will be websitename + WebsiteID
    $WebsiteID = 1  # If 1 is not free, search for the next free ID
    $ApplicationNameTemplate = "TestApplication"
    
    # Search for free websiteID. Startingpoint is $WebsiteID
    $IDsInUse = (Get-IISSite).ID
    while ($WebsiteID -in $IDsInUse) {
        $WebsiteID = $WebsiteID + 1
    }
    
    # Build variables for later
    $WebsiteName = $WebsiteNameTemplate + "_" + $WebsiteID
    $WebsiteHostHeader = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($env:COMPUTERNAME).HostName
    $Binding = "*:" + $Bindingports[$WebsiteNumber] + ":" + $WebsiteHostHeader
    $ApplicationName = $ApplicationNameTemplate + "_" + $WebsiteID
    
    # Write some progress (and no, it does not affect performance)
    $WebsiteNumber += 1 
    $Status = $WebsiteNumber.ToString() + " of " + ($NumberOfnewWebsites).count.ToString()
    Write-Progress -Activity "Creating Websites" -CurrentOperation $WebsiteName -Status $Status -PercentComplete (($WebsiteNumber / $NumberOfnewWebsites.count) * 100)

    # Create folders for the application
    $WebsiteDirectory = "d:\websites\jndata\$WebsiteName"
    $ApplicationDirectory = "d:\websites\jndata\Applications\$ApplicationName"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $WebsiteDirectory -Force | Out-Null
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $ApplicationDirectory -Force | Out-Null

    # Create Website with a webapplication
    # Website
    $ConfigSectionCollection = Get-IISConfigSection -SectionPath "system.applicationHost/applicationPools" | Get-IISConfigCollection
    New-IISConfigCollectionElement -ConfigCollection $configSectionCollection -ConfigAttribute @{"name" = "$ApplicationName"; "autoStart" = $true; "managedPipelineMode" = "Integrated" }
    $TestSite = New-IISSite -Name $WebsiteName -BindingInformation $Binding -PhysicalPath $WebsiteDirectory -Passthru
    # Application
    $TestSite.Applications.Add("/$ApplicationName", $ApplicationDirectory) | Out-Null
    $TestSite.Applications["/$ApplicationName"].ApplicationPoolName = "$ApplicationName" 
    # Commit (To storage?)
    Stop-IISCommitDelay
} -End { 
    # Stop-IISCommitDelay
}
$Status = "Done. Created " + ($NumberOfnewWebsites).count.ToString() + " websites."
Write-Progress -Status $Status -Activity "Creating Websites"
```

Comment: PowerShell 5.1? Can you reproduce this with latest PowerShell? Also try not to use `webadministration` any more.

Comment: In this specific situation I'm actually using iisadministration cmdlets.
I've just tried a run without webadministration import, same behaviour.
And neither webadministration nor iisadministration works with newer versions of PowerShell anyway, hence the #Requires -PSEdition Desktop
https://github.com/PowerShell/WindowsCompatibility/issues/84

Comment: If you are familiar with analyzing the dumps then you could collect them via [DebugDiag Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210#:~:text=The%20Debug%20Diagnostic%20Tool).